# Fitting a normal distribution from a generator

Tags: scipy, distribution, normal-distribution

Fitting a distribution with sciPy is straightforward when the data are in a list:

```
import scipy as sc
data = sc.stats.norm.rvs(5.0, 2.0, size=100)
mu, std = sc.stats.norm.fit(data)
```

But my data are coming from a generator. norm.fit don´t directly work with generators. Transfering the whole data to a list before giving them to norm.fit is not possible. Is there any other library to solve my problem?

Comment: Why isn't it possible to transfer the data to a list? In any event, if the data is too large to fit in memory, perhaps you can directly compute the sample mean and sample variance, though that might not match the output of a more sophisticated approach to fitting a distribution to the data. On the other hand, if the sample size is so large that you can't put it in a list, sample mean and variance should be quite accurate.

Comment: Computing directly is the way i´d like to avoid as it is most likely slower than any library.
Getting samples isn´t trivial either as the data can be sorted in any way. There will be ways, but accuracy is quite important in my case, so samples aren´t an alternative.

Comment: If there is a library `sum` which can handle generators which return vectors and compute the sums component-wise, perhaps you can (using something like `map`) create a generator which returns elements which look like `[1,x,x**2]` (or whatever the scipy syntax of vectors is) and get the sum of all such. Once you get `n`, `Sx` and `Sx^2` you can assemble the sample mean and variance.